# How can I combine the results of 3 queries in MongoDB?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongojs

I made the following filter in hopes that I would be combining the results from all 3 `$and` arrays but it is only matching one of those blocks.

How can I combine the results of what would be returned from each `$and` array if conditions are met. Hopefully that's clear. I don't know what to call the `$and` array.

```
const filter = {
      $or: [
        {
          $and: [
            { category: req.query.category },
            { tags: req.query.subCategory },
            {contentType: req.query.contentType},
            req.query.searchTerm !== ""
              ? {
                  name: {
                    $regex: "(?i)" + req.query.searchTerm + "(?-i)",
                    $options: "i",
                  },
                }
              : {},
          ],
          $and: [
             { category: req.query.category },
            { tags: req.query.subCategory },
            {contentType: req.query.contentType},
            req.query.searchTerm !== ""
              ? {
                  description: {
                    $regex: "(?i)" + req.query.searchTerm + "(?-i)",
                    $options: "i",
                  },
                }
              : {},
          ],
          $and: [
             { category: req.query.category },
            { tags: req.query.subCategory },
            {contentType: req.query.contentType},
            req.query.searchTerm !== ""
              ? {
                  tags: {
                    $regex: "(?i)" + req.query.searchTerm + "(?-i)",
                    $options: "i",
                  },
                }
              : {},
          ],
        },
      ],
    };
 await Content.paginate(filter, options, (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        res.status(500).send(err);
      } else {
        res.json(result);
      }
    });
```

EDIT: Below is an example of two entries that would be found in the database. The way it should work is it should use `category`, `subCategory`, and `contentType` to filter out the entries in the database so that what I have now are only the entries which have the same `category`, `subCategory`, and `contentType` as specified in `req.query`, I'll call this the `firstFilterResult`. From there, I am trying to search within `firstFilterResult` to see if I have entries that have `name`, `tag`, or `description` matches. So basically `catgeory`, `subCategory` and `contentType` are just used to narrow down the results so that I can find matches for `name`, `tag`, and `description`. My code above doesn't do exactly this but this is the idea behind it and I thought that what I have would do similar, but I guess I'm wrong.

```
contents: [
      {
        tags: [
          'food',
          'drinks',
          'card',
          'account'
        ],
        _id: '1d13ff7m6db4d5417cd608f4',
        name: 'THE NAME FOR THIS PIECE OF CONTENT',
        description: 'In here I will begin to talk about...',
        content_id: '5dbcb998ad4144390c244093',
        contentType: 'quiz',
        date: '2019-06-03T04:00:00.000Z',
        category: 'food',
        image: 'https://IMAGE.PNG',
        __v: 0
      },
      {
        tags: [
          'computer',
          'laptop'
        ],
        _id: '7d1b940b1c9d44000025db8c',
        name: 'THE NAME FOR THIS PIECE OF CONTENT',
        description: 'This is another description',
        content_id: '5f1b963d1c9d44000055db8d',
        contentType: 'tool',
        date: '2019-06-03T04:00:00.000Z',
        category: 'money',
        image: 'https://IMAGE.PNG',
        __v: 0
      }
 ]
```

Comment: `$or: [ {$and: expr}, {$and: expr}, ... ]` should do what you are trying to do.  Perhaps if you post 3 or 4 representative docs we can see the issue.   Also: the `$and` exprs appear to the same...?

Comment: This is different in each 
```$and` expression.  tags: {
                    $regex: "(?i)" + req.query.searchTerm + "(?-i)",
                    $options: "i",
                  },```
this one has 'tag' while the others have 'description' and 'name'

Comment: And the proof that isn't working is that if I remove 2 of the `and` expressions then I get different results. For example if I have only the one that has 'tags' then I get the correct results for that query, but then i add description and I lose those original results and they are replaced with whatever is returned in the description one

Comment: I edited the example, hopefully that makes more sense?

Comment: Try logging the value of `filter` after constructing it, to make sure it actually looks the way you intended.

Comment: Currently this is the value of filter: `{ '$or': [ { '$and': [Array] } ] }` which seems correct to me, but it is only returning results that match `tags` because that is last filter. IDK why tho. @Joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it to work with this

```
 const catFilter =
      req.query.category !== "" ? { category: req.query.category } : {};
    const subCatFilter =
      req.query.subCategory !== "" ? { tags: req.query.subCategory } : {};
    const typeFilter =
      req.query.contentType !== ""
        ? { contentType: req.query.contentType }
        : {};
    const filter = {
      $and: [
        {
          $or: [
            {
              name: {
                $regex: req.query.searchTerm,
                $options: "i",
              },
            },
            {
              description: {
                $regex: req.query.searchTerm,
                $options: "i",
              },
            },
            {
              tags: {
                $regex: req.query.searchTerm,
                $options: "i",
              },
            },
          ],
        },
        catFilter,
        subCatFilter,
        typeFilter,
      ],
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Since each element of the `$or` contains the same 3 checks with a single one that varies, these can be separated out, and the `$or` is then only needed if a search term is specified.

Passing `options:"i"` makes the entire regex match case insensitive, so it is not necessary to surround the search string with `(?i)` and `(?-i)`

The following should build the filter that you are attempting, without using empty objects:

```
// base query that checks the common fields
var filter = {
               category: req.query.category,
               tags: req.query.subCategory,
               contentType: req.query.contentType
};

// if a search term is provided, add in the additional critera
if (req.query.searchTerm !== "") {
  var regex = {
               $regex: req.query.searchTerm, 
               options:"i"
  };
  filter['$or'] = [
       { name: regex },
       { description: regex },
       { tags: regex }
  ]
}
```

If this doesn't obtain the results you're after, please edit the question and add in some sample documents so we can see the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work :/ if I plug this in, then nothing is returned in my search results. I added additional content, and thank you for your help!